# Disable hostname verification on org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest;

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, jax-rs, resteasy

I am trying to invoke a rest service by using the abovementioned client. How can i disable hostname verification ?

Comment: What version of RESTEasy are you using?

Comment: <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId><version>2.3.10.Final</version><artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId><version>3.0.6.Final</version>
<artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId><version>3.0.10.Final</version>

Comment: This doesn't look quite right. You're using three different versions of RESTEasy. I'd highly suggest using the same version and hopefully a much newer version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research it seems that the only way to disable hostname verification with RestEasy is to use org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder and setResteasyClientBuilder.HostnameVerificationPolicy.